# Strawberry seeds

Tags: modeling

I would like to model a strawberry:

[image]

However, I don't know how to model the all around the strawberry. I already made the basic shape: [image]

Comment: This tutorial seems like it could be good for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHt6Miij8Hw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Final:

[image]

### TL;DR

1. Create base shape.
2. Select vertices where seeds should be and add them to **Vertex Group**.
3. Create seed model and use it in **Particle System** with **Density** from **Vertex Group**.
4. **Bake AO** map.
5. Use **AO** as a **Displacement**.

### Semi-detailed steps:

### **Shape.**

[image: shape]

You can create base shape using any method you want. The important thing here is that we will use vertices for seed placement so you should have this in mind. [Unwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html) this mesh.

### **Seeds Vertex Group.**

[image: vg]

Select all vertices, than deselect the top and bottom one (if you have triangle fan there as I am). After that choose **Select > Checker Deselect**.

Select/deselect more vertices especially at the top and bottom to have a little bit realistic result.

Add your selection to **[Vertex Group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/index.html)** and check how many you have there.

### **Particle system.**

[image: particles]

Add **Particle System** to your mesh. For **Emission > Number** use the number of vertices from previous step.

Use your seed model as **Object** and make it bigger than you will want them finally (it's for **AO Bake**). You can use **Size** > **Random** to have some variations.

Check **Rotation** for better seed placement. I've added a little bit random there.

Tweak **Emitter Geometry > Normal** so seeds would hover over the mesh.

### **AO Bake.**

[image: ao]

Create new texture for **AO Map**. I've used 4096x4096 32Bit.

[Bake AO](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/baking.html) for this texture. Use **Sampling > Samples > Render** with high value to remove noise. I've used 500 samples but it is too low number.

### **Displacement.**

[image: disp]

Add **Subdivision Modifier** and set it to 4-5.

Add **Displacement Modifier** and use baked map as **Displacement Texture**. Use **Texture Coordinates > UV**.

Tweak **Strength** and **Midlevel** as you like.

You can also tweak texture in **Texture tab** using **Contrast/Brightness** values to get smoother/harder result and set **Filter Size** to **5** (check **Minimum Filter Size**) to get texture blurred.

### **Final touches.**

In **Particle System** you can now lower seeds size and correct **Emitter Geometry > Normal** if needed.

You can use baked **AO Map** as **Bump Map** to emphasize indents.

You can also use [Lattice](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/lattice.html) along with [Lattice Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) to distort your mesh.

[image: lattice]

### Blend file:

[image]

### Bonus:

As a bonus, here is material setup from final render:

[image: bonus]

Comment: Jeez, that might be the most elaborate answer I ever received. Thanks a ton man!

Comment: @JuanNaym it was nice and a little bit challenging question (how to make it semi-automatic and easy to replicate), not my longest answer here though ;) I think I will edit it a bit. There is some inconsistency with indents for seeds caused by poorly unwrapped mesh. I'll need to find a better way for it.

Comment: @JuanNaym It wasn't UV Map, I didn't set origin of seed to it's center... Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C > Origin to Center of Mass (Volume). And also you can control position of seeds on Z axis by changing Velocity > Emitter Object > Z.

Answer (score 3):

You could always find a strawberry texture that comes with a bump map or normal map and apply it to the shape. However with a normal map it won't physically be bumpy it wont effect the shape of the model with bump maps you can create the bumps where the seeds go and maybe model seeds and place them in the recessed areas created by the bump map.

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess it all depends on how close the camera is going to be to the strawberries. If you want it as close as the picture you provided, I am afraid there is no quick method for this. If its going to be further away from the camera I would suggest something like Alex Pensotti's answer.

But for the tedious, up close way, you could do this.

Subdivide your strawberry to about level 4 or 5 like this. 
[image]

Then go to sculpt mode and choose the blob brush with subtract selected. Make the brush the size of the holes you want to create by hitting "F" and dragging mouse, then manually punch in all the holes you will need. 
[image]

Then you need to make your seed, after you have it textured and shaded the way you want you will need to manually place these in all the holes you just created. 
[image]

This was the best way I could think to do it. Maybe someone else has a more automatic way of doing it with particles or something.

I guess you don't have to subdivide and you could use dynotopo instead, but after adding all those holes I'm afraid your topology will be so bad that it would be better do just subdivide it, so you get nicer reflections.

Comment: The only speedup I could think of would be to select a vertex at the bottom of each 'well', duplicate and separate that selection and use dupliverts to place the seeds.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for geometry nodes.

Use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

and with this node setup:

[image]

you can do this:

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

i just found out a more elegant way doing this:

[image]

```
Note: this simple solution might not look that good at the top and the bottom, but here you can use the technique from the first part of my answer to cut them off.
```

Comment: Sorry ... It doesn't look like a strawberry seed distribution pattern, now ... Any way to enhance technique? Thanks

Comment: For sure…needs some time. Will Update

Comment: @vklidu: i update my answer