# Is it possible to convert displacement node to "baked" geometry (OBJ, FBX, etc)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I'm wondering if the displacement achieved using a displacement node in cycles can be "baked" into a mesh with traditional geometry. Is that possible?

Comment: check out the answers to this question - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104672/strawberry-seeds

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CG cookie posted a work-around for something like this... does this process work for you?:
[Convert Material Displacement to a Mesh with Blender 2.8 - Bonus Tutorial](https://youtu.be/McALCOr39rY)

he uses an .exr map baked from the shader, and applies that in a displacement modifier. It's a process unique to this video

Comment: Please elaborate.  Link only answers rely on the link being valid, and are often deleted.

Comment: Not in a commend, [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/170263/edit) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not that I know of if you are referring to the adaptive subdivision with the experimental option enable that displacement only happens at render time.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help! I've been curious about that for a while. It's too bad because I'm able to get some very interesting voronoi designs using nodes that don't seem as easy or possible to do with the textures/displacement method.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I couldn't figure baking either. There is a tedious workaround I used for a project. For every frame you want the animation, duplicate the displacement modifier, then apply it as a shape key. Let's say you have 30 frames, you should have 30 shape keys + basis. Then use those shape keys to animate the object frame by frame (set the first shape key to 1.0 on first frame, set the second one to 1.0 on second and so on)

For certain cases, just creating a couple shape keys and crossfading from one to the other might be enough.